# How to cast DataTableReader to NpgSqlDataReader

Tags: c#, serialization, npgsql

I'm trying to cast DataTableReader to NpgSqlDataReader (its an abstract class)
with no success.
tried inheriting from it but than i cant because it has internal function that could not be override.
The final thing im trying to do is move an object of  NpgSqlDataReader  from one process to another.

Thanks for the help.

Code:
    DataTable td = (DataTable)formatter.Deserialize(Stream1);
    DataTableReader TableRd = td.CreateDataReader();
    NpgSqlDataReader rd= (NpgSqlDataReader) TableRd;

Comment: Could you post your code attempts please so we have an idea of what it is that you are doing that you can't get working.

Comment: I'm just making an DataTableReader Object and want to cast it to NpgSqlDataReader